# Override rails helper route methods to set layout from a GET parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm trying to change the layout of my application according to a GET parameter passed in the URL of each request : `&layout=name_of_the_layout`.

And in my application_controller :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout :get_layout_from_params

  private
  def get_layout_from_params
    if params['layout']
      params['layout']
    else
      'application'
    end
  end
end
```

It works fine, but to "persist" the layout when the the user navigates in the application, I need to add this parameter on each rails route helper in my views (even for POST requests in forms…):

```
ressource_path(@ressource, :layout => get_layout_from_url())
```

where `get_layout_from_url()` is a helper that checks if the `params['layout']` is set in the URL, validates then returns it.

This is definitely not DRY... How can i override every route helper to include this behavior without writing any additional code in my views? I would like to call the standard rails methods in my views : `ressource_path(@ressource), ...`

Or is there a smarter way to achieve this?

PS : Im using rails 3.2.3

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was the old and deprecated `default_url_options` now replaced by `url_options` :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def url_options
    { :layout => validate_layout }.merge(super)
  end

  def validate_layout
    # some stuff reusable
    params[:layout]
  end
end
```

If it doesn't fit, it is close.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would better store it in session instead of appending it to the url for every request.

In rails, you could use session in a very simple way:

```
def get_layout_from_params
  if params['layout']
    session['layout'] = params['layout']
  else
    session['layout'] || 'application'
  end
end
```

If there is a `params['layout']`, it means the user is going to change the layout, so you assign it to the session.

If there is no `params['layout']` given, then it checks if there is `session['layout']`, return it or return `'application'` if session['layout'] is false or nil.

--- edit ---

the following version even shorter, see if you like it or not:

```
def get_layout_from_params
  session['layout'] = params['layout'] || session['layout'] || 'application'
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, this is definitely a clean way to manage this, but I really need to pass the layout parameter in the URL on every request, since the user can access both layout during the same session...